# Can webpack 4 modules be configured as to allow Jasmine to spy on their members?

Tags: typescript, webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine, webpack-4

I've been unable to get my test jasmine test suite running with webpack 4. After upgrading webpack, I get the following error for almost every test:

```
Error: <spyOn> : getField is not declared writable or has no setter
```

This is due to a common pattern we use to create spys for simple functions is:

```
import * as mod from 'my/module';
//...
const funcSpy = spyOn(mod, 'myFunc');
```

I've played around with `module.rules[].type` but none of the options seem to do the trick.

This webpack [GH issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5834) indicates ECMA modules are meant to not be writable which makes sense for the web but is there really no workaround for testing?

Relevant package versions:

```
"jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
"typescript": "2.5.3",
"webpack": "4.1.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-webpack": "^2.0.13",
```

Answer (score 26):

There's `spyOnProperty` which allows treating a property as read-only by setting the `accessType` argument to `'get'`.

Your setup would then look like

```
import * as mod from 'my/module';
//...
const funcSpy = jasmine.createSpy('myFunc').and.returnValue('myMockReturnValue');
spyOnProperty(mod, 'myFunc', 'get').and.returnValue(funcSpy);
```

Comment: Weird but this doesn't work for me. It fails with the following error: ===Error: <spyOnProperty> : myFunc is not declared configurable===. This is how I declared my function: export var myFunc = function(){...};

Comment: See fixedSpyOn function here github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414#issuecomment-457878397

Comment: @AmerMograbi did you find a way to avoid your error ?

Comment: use this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852549/error-spyonproperty-function-is-not-declared-configurable/68981304#68981304

Answer (score 3):

There's [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6979) where they arrive at the same conclusion; that immutable exports are intended. But user **lavelle** has a workaround (in [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6979#issuecomment-379414342)) where they've created different webpack configs for test and production code. The test config uses `"commonjs"` modules, which seems to have worked for them by not creating getters.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Anton Poznyakovskiy's answer:

I've added this TypeScript function to my shared testing module as a convenience:

```
export const spyOnFunction = <T>(obj: T, func: keyof T) => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpy(func as string);
  spyOnProperty(obj, func, 'get').and.returnValue(spy);

  return spy;
};
```

Example usage:

```
import * as mod from 'my/module';
//...
spyOnFunction(mod, 'myFunc').and.returnValue('myMockReturnValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, it is possible to wrap the methods in custom class and then mock it.

Example below:

```
//Common Utility

import * as library from './myLibrary'

export class CustomWrapper{
    static _func = library.func;
}

//Code File
import { CustomWrapper } from './util/moduleWrapper';

const output = CustomWrapper._func(arg1, arg2);

//Test File 

import { CustomWrapper } from './util/moduleWrapper';

spyOn(CustomWrapper, '_func').and.returnValue('mockedResult');
```