# How to mock/spy an imported function in Angular unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, mocking, spy

Let's say i have an angular 6 component with a method `test` which returns some value:

```
import { doSomething } from './helper';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    test() {
        const data = doSomething(1);
        return data.something ? 1: 2;
    }
}
```

`doSomething` is just a simple helper function:

```
export function doSomething() {
    return { something: 1 };
}
```

Is it possible to mock or spy this function in a unit test (so i can control its returnValue)? Or do i have to change my approach in the component?

Please note: `doSomething()` can be a lodash function, a const, a class etc. I just tried to keep the example as simple as possible.

---

Things i've tried:

- `SpyOn` doesn't work because function is not attached to anything
- Importing an mock-function into the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` gives `Unexpected value 'doSomething' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`
- Creating a service for it works but it feels silly to have to create services for each imported function

Comment: May I ask why you want to mock it? You also mentioned `SpyOn`, which  implies spying instead of mocking.

Comment: I want to be able to control the returnValue of the function so i dont have to care about logics in this function since it should have a separate unit test. Maybe mocking is the wrong word. Spying would also be good as long as i can control the return value within the unit test

Comment: you can try spyOn(service, 'function').and.returnValue('your value here')

Comment: @FatehMohamed What would `service` be though? `doSomething` does not belong to an object or so

Comment: You are right: the function should have it's own test.  But here's the thing: The function should always return the same output for a specified input and you should be able to control the input in your tests. If that's not the case then that could be a sign of a design issue. I assume you can instruct the build process to include a different file in your tests, but I rather encourage you to rethink the approach.

Comment: I agree, but wouldnt that actually make a stronger case for mocking/spying? I expect returnValue x when y is inserted, and A when B is inserted. What if this function requires 2 classes who both also require parameters. Seems a lot of work and error prone.

Comment: @abetteroliver How would you approach it differently though? :)

Comment: It really depends on your actual use case / code. Maybe you can show us a more realistic example. The basic idea of unit testing is that you don't care about the implementation (the internals) during testing. You call `doSomething` today, but you may call another function tomorrow and call an internal function next month. You don't want to rewrite your tests everytime.

Comment: Thats why mocking/spying is perfect. Because i indeed don't care about the internals during testing. I simply want to cover the possible outcomes so i can unit test my function properly. Let's turn it around. Why would you not mock/spy something?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In your spec file import the helper this way:

```
import * as helper from './helper';
```

And in your it() you can spy on the helper object and return the requested value:

```
spyOn(helper, 'doSomething').and.returnValue({});
```

Comment: When trying this, i get the following error:
Error: <spyOn> : doSomething is not declared writable or has no setter
Angular 7 (CLI)

Comment: same. @rryter did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm afraid not yet.

Comment: @PeterI I posted a solution in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54757283/1387126

Comment: See fixedSpyOn function here https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414#issuecomment-457878397

Comment: From the same issue, but different case - which was my case - and different solution (via tsconfig): https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414#issuecomment-501209914

Comment: use this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852549/error-spyonproperty-function-is-not-declared-configurable/68981304#68981304

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to mock an external function, but you can do something like following which is working fine.

```
import { doSomething } from './helper';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    const doSomethingRef = doSomething; 
    test() {
        const data = this.doSomethingRef(1);
        return data.something ? 1: 2;
    }
}
```

Now, since we can mock `doSomethingRef`

```
describe('AppComponent ', () => {
  let appComponent: AppComponent ;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    appComponent= TestBed.inject(AppComponent);
  });

  it('should allow mocking', () => {
    (appComponent as AppComponent).doSomethingRef = jasmine.createSpy('doSomethingRef ').and.returnValue(1);
    expect(guard.test()).toEqual(1);
  });
 }
```