# How to mock rxjs webSocket in Jasmine?

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs, jasmine

Here is my chat service:

```
import {webSocket, WebSocketSubject} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import {delayWhen, retryWhen, take} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {timer} from 'rxjs';

...

export class ChatConnectionService {

  private readonly _connection: WebSocketSubject<any>;
  public readonly messages$: Observable<ChatInboundMessage>;

  constructor() {
    this._connection = this.getConnection();
    this.messages$ = this._connection.asObservable();
  }

  private getConnection(): WebSocketSubject<any> {
    return webSocket(`.../chat`);
  }

}
```

And here is what I've tried so far:

```
import * as rxJsWebSocket from 'rxjs/webSocket';

describe('ChatConnectionService', () => {
  let service: ChatConnectionService;

  const subject = new Subject();
  let webSocketSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {   
    webSocketSpy = spyOnProperty(rxJsWebSocket, 'webSocket', 'get').and.returnValue(<any>subject);

    service = new ChatConnectionService();
  });

  it('should create a new connection when service instantiated', () => {
    expect(webSocketSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
 Error: <spyOnProperty> : webSocket is not declared configurable
```

How to replace `webSocket` with a Subject so I can test it? RxJs: 6.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no good solution for this, there is a similar topic about `fromEvent` operator here:
[Error: <spyOn> : fromEvent is not declared writable or has no setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214234/error-spyon-fromevent-is-not-declared-writable-or-has-no-setter).

If the intention is to spy directly on the operator, then the only working option seems to be the targeting `ES5`, which I do not consider as a solution, because a deployed `ES6+` could reduce the bundle size.

I guess the best option could be having a wrapper function for the `webSocket` operator. The wrapper function can already be spied upon. In your example the easyiest way would be setting up a spy for the `getConnection()` function, which has the responsibility of returning the connection instance.