# Stub file imports in Angular 2+ Unit Testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, stubbing, angular-unit-test

My project has a lot of utility functions that perform some data transformations, etc.
These functions are not in class and are reused in many utility files.

I'm very new to angular testing. Searched for quite some time and I couldn't find a way to stub the imports of a tested file. Here's the example:

**/utils/helpers.ts**

```
export const sumNumber = (a: number, b: number): number => {
  return a + b;
}
```

**/utils/file-i-want-to-test.ts**

```
import { sumNumber } from "./helpers";

export const sumArrays = (arr1: number[], arr2: number[]): number[] => {
  const len = arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr1.length : arr2.length;
  const result = new Array(len).fill(0);

  return result.map((_, index) => sumNumber(arr1[index] || 0, arr2[index] || 0));
}
```

**/utils/file-i-want-to-test.spec.ts**

```
import { sumArrays } from './file-i-want-to-test';

describe('Utilities', () => {

  describe('Function - sumArrays', () => {

    it('should return empty array', () => {
      const actual = sumArrays([], []);
      expect(actual).toEqual([]);
    });

    it('should call sumValue 2 times', () => {
      const actual = sumArrays([1, 2], [3, 4]);

      // How to test that sumArray is actually calling his dependency sumNumber?
    });
  });
});
```

**Problem**

In order to unit test function *sumArrays* properly, I need to stub it's dependency *sumNumber*.
How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import * as helpers from './helpers'; // import helpers like so

describe('Utilities', () => {

  describe('Function - sumArrays', () => {

    it('should return empty array', () => {
      const actual = sumArrays([], []);
      expect(actual).toEqual([]);
    });

    it('should call sumValue 2 times', () => {
      spyOn(helpers, 'sumNumber'); // this just stubs it to return undefined
      const actual = sumArrays([1, 2], [3, 4]);
      expect(helpers.sumNumber).toHaveBeenCalled(); // expect it was called
      // How to test that sumArray is actually calling his dependency sumNumber?
    });
  });
});
```

The `spyOn` has a richer API as well, `spyOn` just makes it return undefined.

`spyOn(helpers, 'sumNumber').and.callFake(/* your fake function here */);` // can call fake so every time sumNumber is called, you can have your own definition of a function

`spyOn(helpers, 'sumNumber').and.returnValue(2)` // always return 2 when sumNumbers is called

// also can see how many times it was called
`expect(helpers.sumNumber).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);` // called twice
// can see with what it has been called with
`expect(helpers.sumNumber).toHaveBeenCalledWith([1, 2]);` // 1 being a, 2 being b

Comment: Hi. Thank you for thorough explanation. Sadly it didn't work out the way you pointed it out:


`Error: <spyOn> : sumNumber is not declared writable or has no setter
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)`


I've found the answer that worked for me in other thread:
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396736/can-webpack-4-modules-be-configured-as-to-allow-jasmine-to-spy-on-their-members/54757283#54757283)


Thank you anyway