# SpyOn on submodule method returns no spy in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, spyon

I stumble on a problem that I cannot solve. I tried to spy on a sub-modules method but got the error that the moduleSpy is not a spy with the following error message. The module is an npm package.

`Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.`

```js
import * as module from 'package';
import { TOKEN } from 'injectionToken.ts'

describe('ExampleComponent', () => {
    let component: ExampleComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
    let moduleSpy;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        moduleSpy = spyOn(module.sub, 'subModuleMethod');

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations [ExampleComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: TOKEN, useValue: module }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('test specific function call', () => {
        // press button to test the sub module method
        expect(moduleSpy.subModuleMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

})
```

Does anyone have an idea why the spy is not recognized?

Comment: you tried expect(moduleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); ?

Comment: @enno.void i tried it and get a similar error message. `Expected spy subModuleMethod to have been called.`

Answer (score 0):

What you have worked on earlier versions of Angular/TypeScript but not on later versions of it.

This is a long thread explaining it: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414

These are some solutions:
[Can webpack 4 modules be configured as to allow Jasmine to spy on their members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396736/can-webpack-4-modules-be-configured-as-to-allow-jasmine-to-spy-on-their-members/54757283#54757283)

The github thread has some solutions but none of those solutions worked for me.

My favourite solution was this one though:

[Error: supportsScrollBehavior is not declared configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259259/error-supportsscrollbehavior-is-not-declared-configurable/62935131#62935131)